# How to display a map with a traffic layer on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, maps

I'm currently developing a Windows Phone 7 app in which I would like to display a map with a layer of the road traffic.

First, I tried to display a Bing AJAX Map and a Google Map through the webBrowser control. If the map is displayed, the UX is just awful. In fact, the webBrowser control doesn't allow the user to navigate or zoom with his fingers. It captures all the manipulations and doesn't apply them on its content.

Then, I tried to use the Bing Maps control and override the Tile layer with another API like the Nokia one or the OpenStreetMap one (like explained on the Nokia wiki [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Nokia_Maps_for_WP7_using_Bing_Map_Control) and [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Bing_map_API_with_Nokia_Map_and_OpenStreetMap)). It works, but none of these API allows to display a traffic layer (or I can't find the way to do it).

Finally, I used the trick to use the Google Maps tiles with a traffic info layer. If it works, I'm pretty sure that this solution is not legal. Some apps on the Windows Phone Store display the Google Maps with a traffic layer, but if they don't use the Bing Map control and override the Tile layer, I don't know how they do...

Does someone know how to display a map with a traffic layer into a Windows Phone 7 app in a legal way ? Did I miss something ? Maybe there is a solution I don't know or I don't think about ?

I really hope that someone will be able to help me !